# Accessing nested VB.NET classes from VB6 via COM

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6, wrapper, inner-classes

I've got two .NET DLLs from a manufacturer which I have to implement within a  VB6 project. For this I begun writing a wrapper for it in VB.net [based on a Microsoft tutorial](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364069(v=vs.80).aspx).

I don't want to wrap just functions... I want to use the classes of the dll in the VB6 Project. I built a COM-class in the VB.net Wrapper DLL and the VB6 project did recognise it perfectly fine.

**The problem is, when I'm creating nested classes, the VB6 project only recognises the top one**, but not the classes in the class...

The DLL is registered and I used the TLB file which REGASM gave me.

Here are some attempts I made:

**ATTEMPT 1:**

```
<ComClass(CHRABer.ClassId, CHRABer.InterfaceId, CHRABer.EventsId)>
Public Class CHRABer
    '"Here are the COM-GUIDs"
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Structure Test245
        Dim a As Integer
    End Structure

    <ComClass(Volta_Test.ClassId, Volta_Test.InterfaceId, Volta_Test.EventsId)>
    Public Class Volta_Test
        '"Here are the COM-GUIDs"
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
        Dim a As Integer, b As String, c As Integer

        <ComClass(KD_Test.ClassId, KD_Test.InterfaceId, KD_Test.EventsId)>
        Public Class KD_Test
            '"Here are the COM-GUIDs"
            Public Sub New()
                MyBase.New()
            End Sub
            Sub test()

            End Sub
        End Class
        Sub test()

        End Sub
    End Class
    Sub test()

    End Sub
End Class
```

**ATTEMPT 2:**

In the second attempt I just created the classes without any COM-GUIDs and so on. Just created a public class and in the class created another one.

Comment: What access modifiers did you give those nested classes? And are you accessing the nested classes through the outer class like `New NestedClass.InnerClass()`? If you can show some code it would help your question

Comment: They're all public classes. And yes, I'm accessing them via the outer class... 
I can show some of my attempts but not until tommorow because all of the code is on my workstation...

Comment: I've exposed nested C# classes to VB6 using COM, I can't think of any reason why it would not work from VB also.